# Target build and SDK

Tags: android, api, sdk

I am getting into Android app development now, what build should I choose as the target SDK and will my app work on higher APIs? Also, is there no API 20 build for KitKat, I only see one for KitKat Wear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set the API to what users have most, based on the latest numbers https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net I believe you should set at least API 15 or better 16.

Comment: Do you mean I should select my target SDK as API 15/16? Will my application also work on devices that run higher APIs?

Comment: What about the compile with tab, what should I be choosing over there and why does API 20 only show KitKat Wear?

Comment: It's been some years since I wrote code for Android I can't help you with this one.

Answer (score 0):

**minimum required SDK** = lowest version of the android that your app will support(make 10 if you want to target most of the devices, else make 14 or above if you don't want to use support library, good for beginning)

**target SDK** = you should choose it as latest stable version(choose 19 if you don't want support for android wear also)

compile sdk = 19

API 20 is specifically for applications designed for android wearables.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupDevice